# API V2 Musings: What would you like to see

Tags: discussion, api-v2

Answers should take the form of feature requests/modifications that are either obviously beyond the scope of v1 and or have been status-declined or status-deferred

They will be indexed here in the Q.

Answer (score 10):

#### Move the `id` value into the query string

In that the id is vectorized, it is designed to represent multiple values.

Currently the `id` field is a component of the url. This severely constrains the number of records that can be retrieved far below the stated maximum of the max `pagesize` which is 100.

Another, more serious, implication of this limitation is that, with `id` in the url, the limit is arbitrary and undefined, which is never a good thing, requiring trial and error to find the max url length in respect to the variable length `id`, or make many single `id` requests increasing load on the server.

If the `id` were a query string component, it is quite possible to issue a request for 100 items even with large `id`. Currently, using short `id` values, the server starts issuing errors at ~30 items.

What I would like to see:

```
/path?id=123;456;789
```

Which would obviate the necessary hack described [**here**](https://stackapps.com/questions/889/dev-tip-how-to-batch-up-multiple-id-requests-to-maximize-economy-and-still-avoid)

Answer (score 9):

**User Authentication**

This is an obvious one (and a stated goal for V2, I think).

The basics would be for some way to authenticate a user against his StackOverflow/etc user. Also, a way to access the "linked accounts" information would be great (so authenticating a StackOverflow user will automatically give the application knowledge of his other accounts which are linked to the same user).

That last part might be problematic, so some way of letting the user disallow sharing the linked info/informing the user is important.

Comment: Do you have a source for the "stated goal for V2" bit?  The "I think" bit suggests not, I guess...

Answer (score 9):

**Users's Favorite Tags**

Having access to a given user's favorite tags would make it much easier to provide a customized user experience where tailoring to the user's preferences could be automatic.

Comment: this one should be an easy expose and does not seem to pose any privacy issues. too bad it didn't get suggested a few weeks ago.

Comment: this was suggested a while back on the old stack apps beta site and was marked as postponed until v2.

Answer (score 8):

**The ability to post questions/answers.**

This is important for the question-answering robot I'll be making.

Comment: Was I right in interpreting the second sentence of your answer as a joke? :)

Comment: @Maxim: Actually, no... I really am going to write an app that searches the question for key words and then uses an algorithm to look up possible answers on search engines and posts them :)

Comment: Nooo.... How are people supposed to get lots of rep by answering the same noob question every week about their language of choice :)

Answer (score 2):

**The ability to post comments.**

Answer (score 2):

**Administration abilities**

This would allow users with high enough reputation to use apps that could alert them of questions that may need to be closed *and* provide them the means to close said question within the same application.

Answer (score 0):

#### Ability to get at the questions user voted on

At this stage I see no way to get what questions and answers user has voted on. It would be good to have this ability for future releases of my [app](https://stackapps.com/questions/933/stacktagz-graph-your-tag-activity).

Seeing other user's votes is a pretty bad idea as they are meant to be private.

Comment: this information is intentionally omitted. the potential for abuse is far too high. Favorites are the best you gonna get.

Comment: @code: But in v2.0, this could probably be allowed via OAuth or some other authentication method.

Comment: @geo - it's not a matter of determining/controlling *who* can see it, it is a matter of privacy. it will never happen.

Comment: @code: Well... you can see your own votes. Why can't an app authenticating on your behalf see them too?

Comment: @geo - ok, i was not looking at it from that perspective. in the context of igor's app, i can see a use case. but spying on another user's up/downs will never happen, which is what i should have said clearly.

Comment: Oh. It's obvious, now that you said it.