# Why does the API lack any POST methods?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, api

Why aren't any POST methods available?

Being able to post new questions and answers would be very interesting.

Comment: The crowd here is pretty pedantic. When you say POST you really don't mean HTTP POST (although read/write API would imply HTTP POST) but posting questions/answers/comments. Probably best to decapitalize the question and the title :)

Answer (score 7):

They have been very clear that **version 1 of the API will be read only** and they will be revisiting the POST type features (like adding new questions and answers) for the next version of the API. You can post and vote for the features you would like to see in the next version [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/751/api-v2-musings-what-would-you-like-to-see/). You can also view any feature requests which have been deferred to some future version wit the [status-deferred](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/status-deferred) tag.

Comment: This is the correct answer, bpedro.

Answer (score 5):

Read the blog entry about it

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/what-would-a-stack-overflow-api-look-like/